# Sonata sort admin list using a aggregate on a child field

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I am using sonata's admin list to show a table of projects. Each project has many project sites which have 5 different status types. Status types 1-4 are deemed to be active whereas 5 is inactive.

I want to be able to order my list of projects by the count of active project sites it has.

I have created a method on the Projects Entity like so:

```
public function getActiveSitesCount()
{
  $activeSites = array_filter($this->sites->toArray(), function(ProjectSite $site) {
    return $site->getStatus() <= 4;
  });

  return count($activeSites);
}
```

When added to the list view as a column it returns the correct amount of project sites, however when I add it to the `datagridValues` it has no effect e.g:

```
protected $datagridValues = array(
  '_page' => 1,
  '_sort_order' => 'DESC',
  '_sort_by' => 'activeSitesCount'
);
```

I have tried different variations in the `_sort_by` such as `getActiveSitesCount` but it seems to default back to `id ASC`.

I have also tried adding in a `COUNT...ORDER BY` in the `createQuery` function which gives the same default behaviour.

Is it possible to use a value which is not a field in the sort by?